# How to handle open ended pagination using reactive streams?

Tags: amazon-web-services, pagination, rxjs, reactive-programming

I am using [RxJS](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/) for all async request handling in my redux application. One thing in particular I am using it for is enumerating all the results from a paginated AWS API. Those APIs generally do not allow random page jumping, one must call the API with a special token (`nextToken`) from the previous call and follow the sequence. The list is complete when there is no `nextToken` sent with the response.

What I would like to do is have a stream of the partial page results that I can at the end flatten into one array. The expected benefit is that when the user leaves a particular screen in the app that fetched the list, I can unsubscribe them from the stream and the remaining pages (which will never get displayed) won't be fetched.

I am struggling to understand how I can create such a stream relatively "purely" without going into the territory of `Rx.Subject` and pushing the tokens into it manually. I fear that if I do it "manually" like this, I will be exposed to potential memory leaks or other bugs resulting from failure to unsubscribe and other coding errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `expand` operator to implement paging. And you can control the retrieval of the pages using a notifier observable. The `take` and `concatMap` operators can be used to ensure the next page isn't retrieved until the notifier emits.

The notifier can be whatever observable is suitable. For example, you could use a `Subject` and call `next` on it when the user scrolls to the bottom of the list.

This snippet pages through starred repos using the GitHub API - which uses the `Link` header to indicate the URI for the `next` page. Conceptually, this is the same mechanism as with the AWS API (but I can run it in a snippet).

The comments should explain how it works.

```js
// The GitHub API uses the Link header for paging.
// Map the response to an object that contains the content and the
// URI for the next page (if there is one).

function get(uri) {
  return Rx.Observable.ajax
    .get(uri)
    .map(response => ({
      content: response.response,
      next: next(response)
    }));
}

function next(response) {
    const link = response.xhr.getResponseHeader("Link");
    if (link) {
        const match = link.match(/<([^>]+)>;\s*rel="next"/);
        if (match) {
            return match[1];
        }
    }
    return null;
}

// Use a notifier observable to control the paging.
// Here, the notifier is a timer, but it could be a subject that's
// triggered when the used scrolls to the bottom of the list, etc.

const notifier = Rx.Observable.defer(() => {
  console.log("waiting...");
  return Rx.Observable
    .timer(1000)
    .do(() => console.log("notifying..."));
});

// Use the expand operator to retrieve the next page, if there is
// one. The concatMap operator will ensure the next page isn't retrieved
// until the notifier next emits a value (which is ignored).
// The mergeMap operator will flatten the repos in the content array
// into the observable stream - so the observable emits repos and not
// arrays of repos.

const starred = get("https://api.github.com/users/voy/starred")
  .expand(({ next }) => next ?
    notifier.take(1).concatMap(() => get(next)) :
    Rx.Observable.empty()
  )
  .mergeMap(({ content }) => content);

starred.subscribe(
  repo => console.log(`  ${repo.name}`),
  undefined,
  () => console.log("finished paging")
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/rxjs@5/bundles/Rx.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you for putting the time to write this answer. I will take a detailed look at it and get back to mark it as accepted.

Comment: No worries. The key part is the `starred` observable. Because RxJS is push-based, you need to use something like a notifier to stop it paging though everything and pushing the results at you. The notifier could be a subject or an event (e.g. a button) or a timer, etc. Whatever suits the application.

Comment: Took me a while, but I finally got back to this and accepted your answer. Thanks again and thanks for the delay ;-)